# An algorithm to overcome the elements limit posed by the distance matrix API

Tags: php, algorithm, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

Firstly, I've done a StackOverflow search so I know this is new. Kindly read on:

So I have a string array of 9 places and need to find the distance of them from each other to input into an algorithm. I used Google's Distance matrix API and pass those places as origins as well as destination and it gives back a response thro which I make an n x n square matrix like this:

```
0  3201  4584  4821  1628  1218  1786  4738  4897
3122  0  1400  1638  1797  2756  3323  5310  5472
4523  1400  0  237 3198  4156  4723  6711  6872
4760  1638  237 0  3435  4394  4961  6948  7110
1324  1846  3247  3485  0  958 1525  3931  4093
932 2854  4273  4510  1002  0  567 4873  5034
1499  3422  4840  5078  1569  567 0  5440  5602
5061  5359  6760  6998  4019  4959  5526  0  161
5233  5531  6931  7169  4190  5130  5697  171 0
```

In this, both row-wise and column-wise are the place names i.e. the same place array in the same order which is why, the diagonal elements are ZERO (although in reality Google's response isn't always 0 for some reason) since going to a place from itself should be 0.

Now the issue is that the Google distance matrix API has a 25-elements per request limit where the sum of the count of origins and destinations shouldn't exceed 25. So since I'm using the same origin and destinations, this breaks it down to 12 elements maximum. But the application I'm building requires calculation of more than 12 places so I was thinking of a workaround.

One idea is to use this kind of logic (it's not real code, I've written it just to show the algorithm/pseudocode):

```
if(count(places) > 12) {
   distanceMatrix = []
   for(place in placesArray) {
      distanceMatrix[] = apiCall->(place, placesArray); // apiCall(origin, dest)
   }
} else {
   response = apiCall->(placesArray, placesArray); // apiCall(origin, dest)
   distancesMatrix = convertResponseToDistancesMatrix(response)
}
```

So basically in this case, if the place count is above 12 places, it would instead fun a for loop where it takes that one place as the origin and all the places as the destinations. This way I would be able to move the limit from 12 -> 25 since it counts 1 origin and 24 destinations. The issue is that still beyond 24, it cannot work. So is there any other way by which I can overcome this? I know that there has to be some way by which I can make multiple requests and fill up the matrix, I'd like to know how since I am unable to think of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how often you are doing this, but word of caution that this could add up very quickly as the number of elements grows.  From [their site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing):

"the number of origins times the number of destinations equals the number of elements.", and elements start at $.01/each.  So if you are doing 25 origins and 25 destinations, that would be 625 elements for $6.25.  For 100, it would be $100.  For 200, it would be $400.  For 1000, it would be $10,000.

If you still want to proceed, here's some pseudocode for how you might do this (assumes that everything including the apiCall is synchronous, and that results are in a 2d array):

```
/**
 * @param locations Array of locations you want to consider
 */
var queryDistances = function(locations) {
    var locationDistances = [];
    var placesToConsiderAtOnce = 12;

    //Get the location groups to consider
    var locationGroups;
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        var locationArraysIndex = Math.floor(i / placesToConsiderAtOnce);
        locationGroups[locationArraysIndex] = locationGroups[locationArraysIndex] || [];
        locationGroups[locationArraysIndex].push(locations[i]);
    }

    //Process all combinations of the location groups
    for(var i = 0; i < locationGroups.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < locationGroups.length; j++){
            var originArray = locationGroups[i];
            var destinationArray = locationGroups[j];
            var results = apiCall(originArray, destinationArray);

            for(var k = 0; k < originArray.length; k++){
                for(var l = 0; l < destinationArray.length; l++){
                    var locationDistancesFirstIndex = k + i * placesToConsiderAtOnce;
                    var locationDistancesSecondIndex = l + j * placesToConsiderAtOnce;

                    locationDistances[locationDistancesFirstIndex] = locationDistances[locationDistancesFirstIndex] || [];
                    locationDistances[locationDistancesSecondIndex] = results[k][l];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return locationDistances;
};
```